# Driver.ExecuteJavaScript<object> returns null

Tags: c#, selenium, automated-tests

If I execute this command from a developer console in Internet Explorer 11,

```
angular.element('viewer-uigrid').scope().$parent.$parent.reportReq.ReportDefinition.DataSets[0].ColumnDefinitions
```

I get back an array of objects.

In test automation, if I attempt to execute that same code using:

```
var colDefs = Driver.ExecuteJavaScript<object>("angular.element('viewer-uigrid').scope().$parent.$parent.reportReq.ReportDefinition.DataSets[0].ColumnDefinitions[0]; ");
```

The colDefs variable comes back as null.  Driver is an object of type OpenQA.Selenium.IE.InternetExplorerDriver and ExecuteJavaScript is an extension available from OpenQA.Selenium.Support.Extensions.

Any idea why the return value in C# is null, but it returns an array from the console?

Comment: add `return` in front of the script: `return angular.element(...`

Answer (score 2):

A co-worker shed light on this.  The correct way to get a value back is to use "return" in your java script string so that the value comes back and isn't discarded, like so:

```
var colDefs = Driver.ExecuteJavaScript<object>("return angular.element('viewer-uigrid').scope().$parent.$parent.reportReq.ReportDefinition.DataSets[0].ColumnDefinitions[0]; ");
```